# choose maven dependencies for apache commons-net

Tags: netbeans, maven-2, apache-commons-net

In a Netbeans (7.2) maven project, I need the FTPClient class contained in the [apache common-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/)

I've searched for the required library typing "commons-net" in the query field.
In the following screenshot you can see what i get.

What is **the difference between items like "20030805.205232" and the ones like "3.2"** and so on?

If I click on the "3.2  [ jar, ftp ]", an "ftp" text appears in the **"Classifier" field**, what does it represent?

Is there a way to access "release notes" for each item, in order to help me in choosing the right dependency?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version item "20030805.205232" means this artifact has been built on August 05/2003 8pm:52. This version was built before 1.0.0.
The classifier means in this case that it is a part of the main project [jar]. If you will add these dependencies you can see they contain different package set. But [jar] & [jar, ftp] have been built by one pom.xml file (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/3.2/).
There is no way to add release notes to item in the dialog but you can select item with [jar] classifier for all general use cases.